# Use PYQGIS to view MS SQL Server temporary table in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, sql-server

I'm working on a QGIS plugin to query a non spatial database held in MS SQL Server and to display the results of the query as a non spatial table in QGIS. I've tried the following:

create global temporary table (I've simplified the select query in this example):

```
sql=("SET NOCOUNT ON;"
        " IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##t1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##t1;"
        " USE MSSQLDatabase;"
        " Select * into [dbo].##t1 from MyTable;")
 conn = pyodbc.connect(con_str, autocommit=True)
 c = conn.cursor()
 c.execute(sql)
```

display the table in QGIS:

```
uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
uri.setConnection(".\SQLEXPRESS", "", "tempdb", "", "")
uri.setDataSource("dbo", "##t1","")
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "t1", "mssql")
```

The code to create the global temporary table works - I can query the temporary table in another app, but my code to display the table in QGIS doesn't produce a valid layer. The QgsDataSourceURI code works if I point it to a non temporary table in the database, but I can't get it to work with a temporary table. Hope someone can spot what I'm doing wrong!